# How do I convert a Bukkit world to vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I ran a small self-hosted Bukkit server for Minecraft version 1.5.2 and later 1.16

I only used a few plugins, e.g. a AutoBackup, nothing game-changing.

Now, for different reasons, I wanted to switch back to Vanilla starting from version 1.16.1.
But the Bukkit server stored the world in three separate folders:

- WORLDNAME
- WORLDNAME_nether
- WORLDNAME_the_end

How can I combine those folders to make the server compatible with a Vanilla server again?

Comment: Related: [Moving from Vanilla Server to Bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27728/185203)